# How to set file permission to a variable

Tags: command-line, scripts

I need to set the file permission number to a variable, so later i can use it in a loop. Can it be done?

Comment: You mean the octal number for permissions , as in `chmod  655 filename.txt` ?

Comment: Yes i need to set that nr 655 into a variable

Comment: Just do `var=655`.   And when you wanna use it, do `chmod "$var" filename.txt`.  Did you try that ?

Comment: But what if i just want to use the last digit, only the 5 for example?

Comment: Please *always* add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) rather than in comments.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide information about what you’re trying to do and what you have so far – maybe there’s an easier way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 5):

In `bash`, you can do that with [`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/stat.1.html) and a [Command Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst), e.g. to save the access rights in octal of file `filename` in variable `var`:

```bsh
var=$(stat -c%a filename)
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting permissions to variable follows the same rules as any other variable:

```bsh
perms=655
```

Notice there's no space between variable name,number, and `=` sign.

As for using that in loop, it's quite simple. Say for example you want to set permissions on everything in Videos folder. You can do

```bsh
perms=655
for i in ~/Videos/*; do
    chmod "$perms" "$i"
done
```

Finally, you can also save permissions from a file, as shown in [dessert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047202/295286). Reusing that in a loop is the same as shown above.

Comment: I realize the loop is meant as an example, but in this case, you could just use `chmod "$perms" ~/Videos/*`.

Comment: What if i want to use only the last digit and then compare in the loop?

Comment: @Redi You can get the last digit with `${perms: -1}`, and use a double-bracket expression, like `[[ ${perms: -1} -lt 7 ]]`, which will return true if the last digit is less than 7. If you need more, please ask a new question.

Comment: @RediRamaj If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.